# If i dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu or Linux from two different storage drives,will i face any perfomance issues?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I am currently working from a Windows 10 laptop,which has two storage drives:

- 1 SSD of 128 GB
- 1 HDD of 1 TB

Windows 10 is installed into the SSD.
If i install ubuntu directly to the completely unused HDD,will i face any performance issues?I'm asking because VM wouldn't work for sure,because my laptop consists of just 4GB of RAM.

I don't see this way of dual booting causing any futute problems,but i want a second opinion to this topic from anyone who has done this before

Thanks!

Comment: There will be no performance issue unless you're into HDD vs. SSD war :)

Comment: Can you install more memory?  I have Ubuntu V18 in a Virtual Machine on Windows 10 and assigned 2 GB of memory to the VM (so I can run other machines simultaneously. It works fine with that memory. I am in Ubuntu now.

Comment: I can upgrade up to 8GB,but i'm more into bual-booting after all

Comment: I find Virtualization to be forward looking strategy for flexibility and dual-booting to be limiting. I stopped that a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There will be no performance issues. The two operating systems are completely independent of each other. Since only one can be run at time, the booted operating system is the only one using the hardware.